# Safe area not work properly on iPhone X when subviews are not in the view area

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, iphone-x

I have a scrollView contains 2 child viewController. You can see VC2 not layout properly.

I found if view is not yet visible onscreen.
`safeAreaInsets` is always 0.

I can call `vc2.view.setNeedsLayout()` to fix this problem when scroll ended.
But the layout is not correct until scroll ended.

The [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891103-safeareainsets) says

> If the view is not currently installed in a view hierarchy, or is not
>   yet visible onscreen, the edge insets in this property are 0.

So how can I fix this situation.

[image]

Autolayout
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information, show us what the constraints of "VC1 Bottom" and "VC2 Bottom" look like. Are they exactly the same?

Comment: Yes.They are same constraints center to safe area & bottom to safe area.

Comment: Have you tired to put `vc2.view.setNeedsLayout()` in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or something like that? (with a proper test to prevent a potential infinite loop)

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is the same. When view is not onscreen safe area is always 0.

Comment: Find any solution for this? I have the same problem and targeting iOS10 I can't use `safeAreaInsets`

Comment: Does same issue happen on other devices (e.g. iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus)? Because you are dealing with `UIScrollView`, it implies some techniques to laying out subviews in a scroll view. This document provides some techniques overview: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html

Answer (score 12):

instead of referencing the current view's safeAreaInsets, set it to the UIApplication:

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
```

Comment: `safeAreaInsets` is only available targeting iOS 11.0 or newer

Comment: Its ok, afaiak older devices do not have safeAreaInsets anyway

Answer (score 3):

In your child view controllers if you set the view controllers `additionalSafeAreaInsets` equal to the window's safe area insets they will layout correctly respecting the safe areas.

I found I had to do this inside of `viewDidLoad()` and `viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIVIewControllerTransitionCoordinator`

Inside of `viewWillTransition` you will want to set the `additionalSafeAreaInsets` in the animation block of the coordinator:

```
coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets
    }
}, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was building a custom paging view controller and ran into this issue as well @PowHU.

The only solution that seemed to work for me was to set the view controller's view class in the storyboard to a custom class I created called `AlwaysSafeAreaInsetsView`.

```swift
import UIKit

class AlwaysSafeAreaInsetsView: UIView {

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    override var safeAreaInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            return window.safeAreaInsets
        }
        return super.safeAreaInsets
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see properly your container view is pinned to the top and bottom of it's superview. Pin it to the Safe Area, and your child view controllers will be laid out properly.

Comment: No. I want container view is the same size as superView.